# angular directive that takes a directive name as a parameter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to create a list/grid that would know to render its items based on some directive where the row rendering directive would be a parameter of the grid.

I was able to create something like this:

```
<div repeat-directive-per-item="directiveName" items="my_items" item-attr="an_item"></div>
```

By returing a synthesised template from a template function but encountered problems when i tired to use this directive inside another directive.

Before i try to resolve those problems I wanted to ask if this could maybe done in some simpler way.

I am looking for some syntax like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="{{itemAttr}} in results" {{rowDirective}} /></div>
```

but it does not seem like ng-repeat is willing to do this type of interpulation.

I know I could also limit the pairs of `rowDirective` and matching `itemAttr` and do an if on them but it feels less general and less elegant.

Comment: What's the ultimate purpose of `{{itemAttr}}` and `{{rowDirective}}`, what should they exactly do? It is hard to suggest something viable without seeing the whole picture. Some simple plunker would be fine.

Comment: rowDirctive is a name of a directive that hopefully will have an isolate scope that has some property to which I want to bind the current result.

Comment: and itemAttr would hopefully allow me to choose a different attibute name for the attribute to which I am binding the current result. so that the "Interface" required from such row rendering directives would only include having a single knows attribute from which they read all their data.

Comment: The case is too complex to describe it with words and potentially contains XY problem, that's why example code is essential if you're looking for simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

> You can not create attribute by using `{{}}` interpolation.

While creating template in directive you could use template function of directive, which can help you to add attribute by accessing `attribute` value.

```
template: function(element, attrs){
   return '<div ng-repeat="{{itemAttr}} in results" '+ attrs.repeatDirectivePerItem +' /></div>'
}
```

Comment: this was more or less my direction, however,  when trying to use this inside another directive It becomes problematic because the parameter are not yet bound to the scope of the containing directive and thus can not be passed to this directive :(